# xslt design mode

Tags: xslt

I have some design issues in my xslt engine.
Quickly, I'm transforming XML documents in other XML documents (first is a metamodel, second is OpenDocument XML).

At one point, I want to output the content text node of an element based upon some conditions.
let's use a dummy example :

```
<father haircolor='blond'>
    <son>
        some text
    </son>
    <sister>
        some stupid text
    </sister>
</father>
```

And I want to output the text node of `<son>` element if its parent is a 'blond father' and if it got a sister following

I have different solutions for this :

First is using precise patterns :

```
<xsl:template match="father[haircolor='blond']>...</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="son[following-sibling::sister]>...</xsl:template>
```

Second is using mode attribute in templates :

```
<xsl:template match="father[haircolor='blond' and son and sister]">
    <xsl:apply-template select='*' mode='ConditionsAreOk'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Third is using a xsl:if in the leaf template :

```
<xsl:template match="son">
    <xsl:if test="parent::father/@haircolor = 'blond' and following-sibling::sister>
         {.}
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

As I'm concerned with the readability and maintenability of my xslt code, I'd like to chose the best way.
To be clear, I don't ask for help about 'how to', but 'Which way is the best'.

My actual thoughts :
I think first way is the most pure XSLT but could be quite hard-core when conditions is complicated and on several elements. I will have to create several specific templates.
I have preference for the last one, because instead of several templates with specific matchs, i have just one with hardcore XPaths in the xsl:if test condition. It's less code and less documentation (but yes, you have to document the XPath or you'll forgot about it in 5 minutes...).

Any opinions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I strongly recommend to avoid as much as possible explicit conditional instructions and to use template match patterns instead**.

In this particular case I'd use:

```
<xsl:template match="father[haircolor='blond']/son[following-sibling::sister]>
  <!-- your code here -->
</xsl:template>
```

So, it is just one single template -- not two -- and the code inside the template body has got rid of difficult to read, understand and maintain conditional instructions.

**My own principle is**:

If the code contains explicit conditional instructions, then it definitely needs improvement.

Comment: Ok. And what do you think about the mode attribute ? If you use it in intermediate levels (for example at father[haircolor='blond'] level) to simplify the XPath at match attributes in next levels. Because I find quite hard to read templates when they got hard XPaths.

Comment: @EricS. modes are useful when the same node would be processed more than once -- by different templates -- otherwise there isn't any meaning in using a mode. I frequently use modes in multi-pass processing -- typically the pass2-processing is done in mode="pass2", ..., etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I personnaly use mode quite as you, multi-processing of one document. But I have to confess using them too when I have several templates for a same node with several complicated Xpath matchs. I'd like to calculate this XPaths 'earlier' (in terms of XML tree) when they are simplier and use then mode with the descending nodes instead of the XPaths in the match attributes. It prevents me from ambiguous template rules too. But maybe it's "dirty"...

Comment: @EricS, No, it's OK as long as the modes aren't too-many and you have a convention for their names and firmly remember which mode means what. Of course, splitting processing into modes can result in duplication and inability to re-use.